# Best Way to Scroll to End of ScrollViewer

Tags: xaml, scroll, windows-runtime

Currently, the only way I have gotten my code to auto scroll to the end when I add a new item is the following:

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="chatViewScroller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="201" Margin="0,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="475" Background="#7FFFFFFF">
    <StackPanel x:Name="chatViewContent" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code:

```
                chatViewContent.Children.Add(
                    new TextBlock() {
                        Text = text,
                        FontSize = 18,
                        TextWrapping = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextWrapping.Wrap,
                        Margin = new Thickness(10, 3, 10, 0),
                        Foreground = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(
                            isServerMessage ? Windows.UI.Colors.Purple : Windows.UI.Colors.Black)
                    });
                await Task.Delay(10);
                chatViewScroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(chatViewScroller.ScrollableHeight);
```

Is this the accepted way of doing it? Do I have to wait for some random period of time?

Comment: Hi, did you find any better solution?

Comment: Would `await Dispatcher.Yield(DispatcherPriority.Input);` work?

Answer (score 16):

Using ActualHeight did not work for me (I have yet to figure out why) - but using ScrollableHeight like this did the the trick:

```
// adding item to ItemsControl...
// ...
_scrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
_scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);
```

Answer (score 15):

For Windows Phone 8.1 I use this:

```
MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(0.0f, double.MaxValue, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Works fine on Windows 8.1 as well

Comment: This is the correct way to do this for UWP apps.  If you use ScrollToVerticalOffset the compiler will give you:  'ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double)' is obsolete: 'ScrollToVerticalOffset may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use ChangeView.'

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion best option is to inherit from ScrollViewer in following way:

```
public partial class AutoScrollViewer
{        
    public AutoScrollViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => this.ScrollToBottom();
    }
}
```

and XAML

```
<ScrollViewer x:Class="AutoScrollViewer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then you can use directly in XAML the new class without additional code behind which is usefull especailly when you have "pure" MVVM code.

Answer (score 2):

no random asynchronicity is never the answer to anything in any language except maybe JavaScript... it just always has that "code smell" you know?

the proper way to do this is to force a "refresh" of the measure of the `ScrollViewer` synchronously to include the newly added children by calling `ScrollViewer.Measure(Size)`

after you "re-measure" the `ScrollableHeight` will be the proper value and you can use it as you normally would..

like this:

```
    private void AddMessage(string text, Color color)
    {
        var message = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = text,
            FontSize = 18,
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 3, 10, 0),
            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color),
        };

        chatViewContent.Children.Add(message);

        chatViewScroller.Measure(chatViewScroller.RenderSize);
        chatViewScroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(chatViewScroller.ScrollableHeight);
    }
```

the `Size` we are using here is the `RenderSize` which could technically be incorrect in some extreme edge cases, but it is pretty close to perfectly ideal for our purposes.  you could also technically use an arbitrarily large `Size` for the `Measure(Size)` and get the same effect.  whatever works best for your solution, hope this helps -ck

Comment: `.Measure` works in WinRT, however it does not work in WP8.1 (sometimes it scrolls, sometimes it doesn't). `chatViewContent.UpdateLayout(); chatViewContent.ChangeView(null, chatViewContent.ScrollableHeight, null);` works in WP8.1 [did not try it in WinRT, may work in both]

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with .NET 3.0 or later, you can use `ScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom()`.

MSDN doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltobottom(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

For WindowsPhone Universal app you can use:

```
 var scrollableHeight = ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
        if (scrollableHeight > 0)
        {
           ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollableHeight);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following:

```
ScrollViewer viewer = GetScrollViewer();
if (viewer != null)
{
    viewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(viewer.ActualHeight);
}
```

Another solution is to put the items into a `ListBox` and use the [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollViewer.ActualHeight) should work, but if your code has just now updated the content of the scroll viewer, you may want to call ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout() before scrolling, so that ScrollViewer.ActualHeight will be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone 8.0, you can use

```
MyScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(MyScrollViewer.ExtentHeight - MyScrollViewer.ViewportHeight);
```

Please also refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset(v=vs.105).aspx